Issue with Filtering Data by Date Input Parameter in Prisma Query
I'm working on a procedure that filters data based on the creation date within the last 24 hours. The code works perfectly when the date is explicitly specified within the procedure:
appReqscreated24H: protectedProcedure
  .query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    return await ctx.prisma.appRequest.count({
      where: {
        created_at: {
          gte: new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        },
        NOT: {
          status: {
            in: [RequestStatus.COMPLETE]
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })

However, when I try to pass the date as an input parameter, the code doesn't work as expected:
appReqscreated24H: protectedProcedure
  .input(
    z.object({
      startDate: z.date()
    }) 
  )
  .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
    return await ctx.prisma.appRequest.count({
      where: {
        created_at: {
          gte: input.startDate
        },
        NOT: {
          status: {
            in: [RequestStatus.COMPLETE]
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }),

I've compared the types and they appear to be identical, yet I'm encountering issues with it not functioning as expected. As someone new to this, I would greatly appreciate any assistance.
Thank you in advance!
